# Dialog from inline content possible?

Tags: jquery, templates, layout, jquery-mobile, modal-dialog

Is it possible to create a [jQuery Mobile dialog](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html) using inline content within the same page?

For example:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">

        <!-- this causes the entire current page to load as the dialog -->
        <a href="#modal" data-rel="dialog">Open Dialog<a> 

        <div id="modal" style="display: none">
            Hello World
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

A typical dialog requires that the href of the linking object be that of a separate "page", or one that sits along side the current page:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#modal" data-rel="dialog">Open Dialog<a>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="modal">
    <div data-role="content">
        Hello World
    </div>
</div>
```

However, my template structure prohibits me from separating the link from the modal content. If possible, I would like to keep things modularized into a single pluggable control. Creating an entirely new external page for the modal content would be cumbersome using my current CMS framework (Sitecore).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not able to find a solid, cross-platform out of the box solution.
But Jquery Mobile 1.2 is having 'popup' role, so any div can easily displayed as popup. http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Answer (score 1):

jQueryMobile - SimpleDialog2 allows inline dialogues
http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/

```
<a href="#" id="opendialog" data-role="button">Open Dialog</a>


  <div id="inlinecontent" style="display:none"   data-options='{"mode":"blank","headerText":"Yo","headerClose":true,"blankContent":true}'>

<ul data-role='listview'><li>Some</li><li>List</li><li>Items</li></ul>
<a rel='close' data-role='button' href='#'>Close</a>
 </div>

$(document).delegate('#opendialog', 'click', function() {
// NOTE: The selector is the hidden DIV element.
$('#inlinecontent').simpledialog2();
})
```